# java.lang.exception no runnable methods junit

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have a suite, inside which I have added the test class.
I am using surefire to run my JUnits.
My test class ends with test and the methods has @test annotations to it.

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Don't describe the code, show it

Comment: Yes this would be the best to show the code.

Answer (score 13):

Here are various suggestions for this incomplete question (for those unfortunate enough to be brought here by google looking for an answer to this common issue):

- if using Junit4.x, just use annotations (@Test); don't create a test suite: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190224/junit-and-junit-framework-testsuite-no-runnable-methods) for details.
- original question said "@Test" annotation is being used, which should prevent the error. But it can still happen if there are other errors that happen earlier, and junit can hide the original problem with this message.  E.g., see if there are problems with Spring configuration (unset @Required attributes), misconfigured mock objects, etc.
- to avoid other frequent issues that also may generate this error (such as running classes suffixed by "*Test" that *do not* have any @Test methods), try updating to the surefire plugin 2.7 (currently @2.8.1) and junit 4.7+ (currently @4.8.1) to avoid [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-482) (i'm using maven3, btw; perhaps do a "mvn clean" before "mvn test" to be safe)
- long shot: upgrade to at least ant 1.7+ (currently 1.8+) to avoid junit 4 [test suite issues](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40682)

Comment: +1 for `mvn clean`, solved this problem for me (after copying project from old machine to new one).

Comment: +1 for "Test" in filename causing problems. Also causes problems at the beginning of a class name. Example: TestHelper.java with no @Test could cause failures.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct version of JUnit at least 4.X to be able to use annotations for that? (Maven?)