# Junit - java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Tags: junit4, runnable

I am doing a tutorial on execute server test cases by using a driver class. The Eclipse error pane showed *error message: java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods*. The error message occurred when 
driver class tried to run exceptionTesting class.

Based pm this post:  [java.lang.exception no runnable methods junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818570/java-lang-exception-no-runnable-methods-junit). It seems like @Test annotation should be used in the test class or updating Junit Jar file to most current version will solve the issue.

Junit Jar file version: 4.11

Please review my code and advise me what modification shall I do to avoid the error message. Thanks!

Driver Class:

```
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

 @RunWith(Suite.class)
 @Suite.SuiteClasses({
     basicAnnotation.class,
     personTest.class,
     exceptionTesting.class
 })
public class UnitTestDriver {

}
```

exceptionTesting class

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class exceptionTesting 
{
  public class junitTest2{
      @Test (expected = ArithmeticException.class)
      public void divisionWithException(){
          int i = 1/0;
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: are you using junit4?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Yes, I am using Junit 4.11 in Eclipse

Comment: Are you sure it is being run as a JUnit 4 test?  Sometimes Eclipse defaults to JUnit 3.  The way to check is to do run as ... to see the launch configuration for that test.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky 1. I clicked on the _Run As_ arrow icon on the top, then select the Run As option->Eclipse showed blank for the Run As section. 2. Execute test suite by right click on the driver class, then choose Run As option->choose Junit Test-->The Junit Pane showed the result as **UnitTestDriver[Runner:Junit4]**. image show Eclipse's run configuration setting http://tinyurl.com/mvt2jfa. Please advise me how to what went wrong in this case. Thanks!

Comment: You are running it correctly.  I see the problem now (posted as an answer.)

Comment: To improve the readability of your code you should consider to follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that junitTest2 is nested inside of exceptionTesting.  You have two choices to solve it:

1) Get rid of the inner class having your tests in the top level class:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class exceptionTesting 
{
      @Test (expected = ArithmeticException.class)
      public void divisionWithException(){
          int i = 1/0;
      }
}
```

2) Have your top level class specify the tests are enclosed and make your inner class static:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.Test;

@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class exceptionTesting 
{
  public static class junitTest2{
      @Test (expected = ArithmeticException.class)
      public void divisionWithException(){
          int i = 1/0;
      }

  }
}
```

Unless you have some reason to need the inner class, #1 is the better choice.  Also note that in Java, convention is to begin classes with uppercase names.  So exceptionTesting would become ExceptionTesting.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Enclosed test runner, which helps to organize test methods hierarchically.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky. Thanks providing me with detailed coding samples. I run into some issue while doing method 2-carry out the test within the nested class. I added *`import org.junit.runners.Enclosed;`*, Eclipse complained _The import org.junit.runners.Enclosed cannot be resolved_. for `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)`, I received error message saying _Class<Enclosed> cannot be resolved to a type_ and _Enclosed cannot be resolved to a type_. Please advise me how to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: What version of JUnit are you on?  I believe Enclosed used to be experimental and in a different package.

Comment: @Jeanne my Junit version is 4.11. Shall I download the newest Junit jar file to resolve this issue?

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky I added junit.4.5.jar file to Eclipse's Java build path. To test method 2 using enclosed class. Eclipse showed the error message _java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type Enclosed not present_. Could you advise me what went wrong in my code? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  It works fine for me on JUnit 4.8.  Are you trying my example exactly as is?