# java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods exception in running JUnits

Tags: java, junit, ubuntu-12.04, junit4

I am trying to run the JUnit on my Linux command prompt `/opt/junit/` contains the necessary JARS(hamcrest-core-1.3.jar and junit.jar) and class files and I am using the following command to run the JUnit:

```
java -cp hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:junit.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  TestRunner
```

TestJunit class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
public class TestJunit {
   @Test
   public void testAdd() {
      String str= "Junit is working fine";
      assertEquals("Junit is working fine",str);
   }
}
```

TestRunner:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println("fail ho gaya"+failure.toString());
      }
      System.out.println("passed:"+result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

I am getting the following exception on running this

```
JUnit version 4.11
.E
Time: 0.003
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(TestRunner)
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:80)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: dunno, was going through beginner tutorials. these files were copied from the tutorial itself. Anyways got my answer, http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/JUnit/Can_You_Explain_the_Exception_No_runnable_meth.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.exception no runnable methods junit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818570/java-lang-exception-no-runnable-methods-junit)

Comment: None of the answers worked. Turns out I had a line of double braces initialization in one of my unit tests...on JDK 8 no less...that, when deleted, caused this error to go away! It was something like myObject.setSomething(new OtherObject() {{/*Put literally anything here*/}});  It took hours to find this (kept thinking my imports were bringing in some bad static initializer from another class, bad classloader, reflection garbage, etc). I believe this *might* be a JVM bug, but have no proof, so I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer. TL;DR "Delete the {{}} part of double brace init.

Comment: I got the same error and when I removed the "public" access modifier on my test class the error disappeared and the tests functioned just fine. Have not dig into exactly why but adding here just in case it helps others.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You will get this exception, if you use the **JUnit 4.4 core runner** to execute a class that has no `"@Test" method`.
[Kindly consult the link for more info.](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/JUnit/Can_You_Explain_the_Exception_No_runnable_meth.html)

courtesy vipin8169

Comment: I am getting this error with Junit5 and I don't have any classes without '@Test'

Comment: In my case, it was due to my @Before method being named setUp() instead of setup()

Comment: I'd like to know what's the class causing the issue. I don't think I'll have to manually check hundreds of classes just because Mockito is too shy to tell me

Answer (score 168):

In my case I had wrong package imported:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

instead of

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Beware of your ide autocomplete.

Comment: In my case it was `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` instead.

Comment: Yeah can be any wrong @Test annotation import, fixing it to org.junit.Test resolves the problem. Ty!

Comment: Does import org.junit.Test; mean that you are using JUnit 4?

Comment: Thanks for saving my time! I too had a testng import.

Comment: @wolf97084 Yes, `org.junit.Test` = JUnit 4, `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` = JUnit 5

Comment: It solves the error or just don't do the test?

Answer (score 48):

My controller test in big shortcut:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TaskControllerTest {
   //...
   //tests
   //
}
```

I just removed "public" and magically it worked.

Comment: Which `public` do you mean?

Comment: Me with exact the same mistake...

Comment: what's the magic behind this fix?

Comment: Thanks. Removed public in front of the class, everything worked after that

Answer (score 22):

*This solution will apply to a very small percentage of people, typically people implementing their own JUnit test runners and using a separate ClassLoader.*

This can happen when you load a class from a different ClassLoader, then attempt to run that test from an instance of JUnitCore loaded from the *system* class loader. Example:

```
// Load class
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(myTestUrls, null);
Class<?>[] testCls = cl.loadClass("com.gubby.MyTest");

// Run test
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.run(testCls); // Throws java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
```

Looking at the stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
```

The problem actually occurs at BlockJUnit4ClassRunner:169 (assuming JUnit 4.11):

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/r4.11/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java#L95

Where it checks which methods are annotated with `@Test`:

```
protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
    return getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(Test.class);
}
```

In this case, `Test.class` will have been loaded with the *system* ClassLoader (i.e.  the one that loaded JUnitCore), therefore technically none of your test methods will have been annotated with that annotation.

Solution is to load JUnitCore in the same ClassLoader as the tests themselves.

---

**Edit**: In answer to the question from user3486675, you need to create a ClassLoader that doesn't delegate to the system class loader, e.g.:

```
private static final class IsolatedURLClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    private IsolatedURLClassLoader(URL[] urls) {
        // Prevent delegation to the system class loader.
        super(urls, null);
    }
}
```

Pass this a set of URLs that includes everything you need. You can create this by filtering the system classpath. Note that you cannot simply delegate to the parent ClassLoader, because those classes would then get loaded by that rather than the ClassLoader of your test classes.

Then you need to kick off the whole JUnit job from a class loaded by this ClassLoader. It gets messy here. Something like this utter filth below:

```
public static final class ClassLoaderIsolatedTestRunner {

    public ClassLoaderIsolatedTestRunner() {
        // Disallow construction at all from wrong ClassLoader
        ensureLoadedInIsolatedClassLoader(this);
    }

    // Do not rename.
    public void run_invokedReflectively(List<String> testClasses) throws BuildException {
        // Make sure we are not accidentally working in the system CL
        ensureLoadedInIsolatedClassLoader(this);

        // Load classes
        Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[testClasses.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<testClasses.size(); i++) {
            String test = testClasses.get(i);
            try {
                classes[i] = Class.forName(test);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                String msg = "Unable to find class file for test ["+test+"]. Make sure all " +
                        "tests sources are either included in this test target via a 'src' " +
                        "declaration.";
                throw new BuildException(msg, e);
            }
        }

        // Run
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        ensureLoadedInIsolatedClassLoader(junit);
        junit.addListener(...);
        junit.run(classes);
    }

    private static void ensureLoadedInIsolatedClassLoader(Object o) {
        String objectClassLoader = o.getClass().getClassLoader().getClass().getName();

        // NB: Can't do instanceof here because they are not instances of each other.
        if (!objectClassLoader.equals(IsolatedURLClassLoader.class.getName())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                    "Instance of %s not loaded by a IsolatedURLClassLoader (loaded by %s)",
                    cls, objectClassLoader));
        }
    }
}
```

THEN, you need to invoke the runner via reflection:

```
Class<?> runnerClass = isolatedClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaderIsolatedTestRunner.class.getName());

// Invoke via reflection (List.class is OK because it just uses the string form of it)
Object runner = runnerClass.newInstance();
Method method = runner.getClass().getMethod("run_invokedReflectively", List.class);
method.invoke(...);
```

Comment: This helped me alot. Thanks!

One remark: It may also be an option, to use the system classloader as parent of your custom classloader. See constructor parameters of [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader-java.net.URL:A-java.lang.ClassLoader-). This way, the parent class loader will try to load the class first, only if this is not possible, the custom class loader will attempt to load the class.

Comment: How would you load JUnitCore in the same ClassLoader as the tests themselves?

Comment: @user3486675 I have added an example of the safest way to do it. It ain't pretty.

Comment: @gubby         Hi Gubby,  the above code does not compile (junit.addListener(...);) and cls is not defined.  We are running into this issue as well and wanted to see how to resolve it.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem now with testing code. That was caused in spring boot because of the `@RunWith` annotation. I have used:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

With that annotation there is JUnit Vintage running which can't find any tests and gives you the error. I have removed that and only JUnit Jupiter is running and everything is fine.

Comment: Yup worked for me as well - I was using junit5 tests with this annotation!

Comment: Worked for me also!

Comment: Explanation: In JUnit5 `@RunWith` was replaced with `@ExtendWith` which is already included in `@SpringBootTest` annotation, so no need to add it.

Answer (score 18):

I had to change the import statement:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

to

```java
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I was using the wrong `Test` import. The correct one was `import org.junit.Test;`

Comment: Thanks, i too faced same issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed but why? Can you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test (Junit 5)
and @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), SpringRunner is on Junit4, junit gets confused.
Removing public before class name will work as
Junit 5 complains about public test classes.
From Docs:
JUnit5 is more tolerant regarding the visibilities of Test classes than JUnit4, which required everything to be public.
In this context, JUnit5 test classes can have any visibility but private, however, it is recommended to use the default package visibility, which improves readability of code.

Answer (score 7):

in my case i just disabled 
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

and there is no exception

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class},
        webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false"})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

Answer (score 7):

For me, replacing `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` with `import org.junit.Test;` helped.

Comment: This really worked for me. Thank you :) Could you please tell the reason why we had to use the other dependency?

Comment: @ImranFaruqi org.junit.jupiter.api.Test comes from JUnit 5 whereas org.junit.Test comes from an earlier major version of JUnit.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this issue and failed to figure out the reason for the same for sometimes. 
Later i found that auto import issue using IDE. That is **imports** of the program.

Basically i was using eclipse IDE. And I was importing a wrong class `"org.junit.jupiter.api.Test"` into the program instead of required class `"org.junit.Test".` Hence check your imports before running any programs.

Answer (score 4):

If using jupiter, please remove @RunWith.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DepartmentServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    DepartmentService service;
    @MockBean
    DepartmentRepository repository;
    @Test
    public void findOneByIdTest(){
        int id = 1;
        Department expected = new Department(1,"401E","AAC01","DL","1");
        when(repository.findOneById(id)).thenReturn(expected);
        Department actual = service.findOneById(id);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After hundreds of test through netbeans unitary test with JUnit, I realized this:

if you add libraries - such as Junit and Hamcrest - **AFTER** creating *Testing for existing class*, your testing class will get `No runnable methods exception in running JUnits`. This is because of default imports:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
```

Instead, should be:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Hope junior developers with this silly problem as me, could have some peace after my comment...

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this if you mix org.junit and org.junit.jupiter annotations inadvertently.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue/error while running JunitCore along side with Junit Jupiter(Junit5)  `JUnitCore.runClasses(classes);` after removing `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and
ran with `@SpringBootTest @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` i am able to resolve the issue for my tests as said in the above comments.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563970/13542839

Answer (score 2):

A bit of heuristic/experience here, I am running a **Spring Boot** project, and I was getting **JUnit Jupiter** tests appearing alongside **JUnit Vintage**. The **JUnit Vintage** ones were failing, when I removed the **public** access modifier the **Junit Vintage** tests disappeared, as a result achieving the behaviour I wanted.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class TestSuiteName {
```

||

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
class TestSuiteName {
```

[Why were JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage separated When I Running TestCase in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822189/why-were-junit-jupiter-and-junit-vintage-separated-when-i-running-testcase-in-in)

Answer (score 1):

**I got this error because I didn't create my own test suite correctly:**

Here is how I did it correctly:

Put this in `Foobar.java`:

```
public class Foobar{
    public int getfifteen(){
        return 15;
    }
}
```

Put this in `FoobarTest.java`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter;
import org.junit.Test;
public class FoobarTest {
    @Test
    public void mytest() {
        Foobar f = new Foobar();

        assert(15==f.getfifteen());
    }
    public static junit.framework.Test suite(){
       return new JUnit4TestAdapter(FoobarTest.class);
    }
}
```

Download `junit4-4.8.2.jar` I used the one from here:

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjunit4jar.htm
```

Compile it:

```
javac -cp .:./libs/junit4-4.8.2.jar Foobar.java FoobarTest.java
```

Run it:

```
el@failbox /home/el $ java -cp .:./libs/* org.junit.runner.JUnitCore FoobarTest
JUnit version 4.8.2
.
Time: 0.009    
OK (1 test)
```

One test passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running test Suite via `@RunWith(Suite.class) @Suite.SuiteClasses({})` check if all provided classes are really test classes ;).

In my case one of the classes was an actual implementation, not a test class. Just a silly typo.

Answer (score 1):

if the class annotated with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) But we class doesn't contain any test methods then we will face this issue.
Solution: if we make to **abstract** we will not get this or if remove public then also we will not face this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Just replace jupiter Test annotation to junit (org.junit) annotation**

Enjoy your coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, I had to use `New > Other > JUnit > Junit Test`. A Java class created with the exact same text gave me the error, perhaps because it was using JUnit 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add @Test annotated method to class where initialisation exception is present.

In our project we have main class with initial settings. I've added @Test method and exception has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by manually adding the junit jar to my project classpath. The easiest way I found to do this was by adding a /lib directory in the project root. Then i just put the junit.jar inside /lib and junit tests starting working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same with my parent test setUp class which has annotation @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and was being extended by other testClasses.
As there was not test in the setUpclass , and Junit was trying to find one due to annotation @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) ,it didn't find one and threw exception

`No runnable methods exception in running JUnits`

I made my parent class as abstract and it worked like a charm .

I took help from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699141/8029525 .
Thanks for help @froh42.

Answer (score 0):

the solution  is simple 
if you importing

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

you have to run as junit 4

**right click ->run as->Test config-> test runner-> as junit 4**

Answer (score 0):

For me I added `JUnit4.12` and `Hamcrest1.3` on the classpath and changed `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` or `import org.testng.annotations.*;` to `import org.junit.Test;`. It finally works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If there is,take out of pom.xml

```
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I missed to add access modifier public to this test-case-method, after added it works. I used JUnit 4. For Junit 5, same test-case works without access specifier to test-case-method.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it worked with Junit5:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class},
        webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false"})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add one more solution for those using Eclipse (and Gradle):

In my case I had a trivial test class such as this one:

```
package somepackage;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest
{
    @Test
    public void test_someClass_doesNotDoThing_whenCreated()
    {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        
        assertFalse( "", someClass.doesThing() );
    }
}
```

This checks all the relevant checkboxes:

- Correct imports are used
- `@Test` annotation is present
- Test method is public
- No different class loader

Still got the "No runnable methods" exception. Apparently Eclipse didn't get the memo which I suspect is prone to occurring when either the test project or some other project in the work space has compilation errors (irrelevant to the test class).

This was resolved by:

- Calling "Refresh Gradle Project" in Eclipse for the entire workspace (possibly optional)
- Calling "Project" -> "Clean" in Eclipse

This made Eclipse understand there was a valid test method in my test class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUnit5 and command, maybe because you missed the target/test-classes in your classpath.
My complete command is as belowing

```
java -jar C:\Libraries\maven-3.5.0\lib\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.10.0.jar "target/classes;target/test-classes;/some .jars"  --select-class "relative path to the test class"
```

Good luck!