# Why were JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage separated When I Running TestCase in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I saw that JUnit5 is released, and i applied in IntelliJ V2016.2.1 and run some testcase.

so saw below screenshot.

[image: a busy cat]

i have just two questions.

1. Why were JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage separated When I Running TestCase in IntelliJ?
2. Can i Merge JUnit 4 and 5 TestResults?

Comment: You can remove the results for the JUnit Vintage. Please, see my answer below.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

JUnit 5 is more than just a new API (called *JUnit Jupiter*). It also contains an abstraction layer for tools to run JUnit tests (called *JUnit Platform*). The platform has no knowledge of either JUnit 4 or Jupiter or anything else really. All it knows are test engines, which will execute the tests they were written for.

(You can read more about this in the [user guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5) or a post I wrote about [JUnit 5's architecture](http://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-architecture/).)

> 1. Why were JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage seperated When I Running TestCase in IntelliJ?

What you see is the launcher executing two engines, the one for the new API (*Jupiter*) and the one for JUnit 4 (*Vintage*). Each engine represents the tests it ran in its own data structure, which IntelliJ shows as the trees you see.

> 2. Can i Merge JUnit 4 and 5 TestResults?

This would have to be an IDE feature, that - as far as I know - is not implemented.

Answer (score 15):

In case, if you use an annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` atop of the class, you can remove it and this will work well. This is what I have before the annotation - it shows that the Junit Vintage failed.

[image]

This is after I removed the annotation:

[image]

Comment: In your second screnshot, I still see the annotation - @RunWith(SpringRunner.class). What is the change that made the vintage test error go away?

Comment: May be screenshot is missing the actual representation but it works as per the solution.