# java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods exception in running JUnits Solution

Tags: java, junit

I have the same issue as this question here: [java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods exception in running JUnits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319697/java-lang-exception-no-runnable-methods-exception-in-running-junits)

The answer says to look at this link: http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/JUnit/Can_You_Explain_the_Exception_No_runnable_meth.html

However, I don't see what the solution to the problem is.  What do I need to add to my code in order to execute the java -cp ... command and not get an error.

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the jar ? check the version of the JUnit library and if its is using JUnit 4.4 core runner to execute a class that has no "@Test" you will face this issue.

Check if there are any classes with no @Test method from test suite and remove them.

also check your package imports for @Test annotation.