# Junit throwing java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods even when public @test is there

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a Springboot, java, maven project.
Here are the version - 
java - 1.8; Junit- 4; SpringBoot version- 2.1.6-RELEASE

There is this TestClass. PFA the code -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        // code
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws ExecutionException {
        // Test method
    }

    static abstract class class1 {
        // code
    }

    static abstract class class2 {
        // code
    }
}
```

When I run this as JUnit, I get the following error message -

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:137)
```

Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods exception in running JUnits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319697/java-lang-exception-no-runnable-methods-exception-in-running-junits)

Comment: Just to be sure you are using BeforeMethod annotation from TestNG package right?

Comment: @MalayShah - Right.

Comment: I tried and the code worked just fine for me. most probably seems like Spring setup issue or the way you are executing it. Can you share how are you executing it?

Comment: Were you able to run it in IDE or the terminal? @MalayShah

Comment: I am running via Eclipse - Run as Junit.

Comment: I executed via Eclipse - I have a maven project where in test resource I created class with your code above and Run as Junit and it worked.